# Empty readonly input fields

Tags: html, accessibility

To my knowledge, read-only fields are used primarily by keyboard-only users so they can focus on the input and copy/paste containing value. But what about fields with no value? Should those be treated as `disabled` since they don't carry any information to the user and from that point of view, it's same like having a disabled button.

Edit:
Those fields are metadata from various sources and if they are empty, most likely it's not even important what they represent because it doesn't add any value to the context, if they can't be updated.

[image]

Comment: Why would you have an empty read-only field? Please elaborate so we can maybe help you.

Comment: Because those fields are metadata from various sources and sometimes there just aren't any info for the specific field. And depending if you have some permission you  are able to edit them or just view the info. And this fields aren't visible only during some form submission but rather all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

No they should be left as `readonly`.

### Long Answer

You need to think about when to use each one:

#### `readonly`

`readonly` fields are to display information back to people.

If that field happens to be blank it should still be returned as people can see that the field exists and contains no information.

This is the same for people who use a screen reader, they get to the field, see it is `readonly`, get the field announced and that it is currently empty. All useful information.

This information will automatically be read out when the form is being read back as well which is useful.

#### `disabled`

`disabled`, however, implies that the field cannot be modified at this moment.

Some screen readers do not read these out by default unless you specifically focus the field with JS etc.

VoiceOver will skip disabled fields - this is not useful if you need the information to be accessible (for example if this is confirmation of previously entered information, skipping an entire field could cause confusion and cause people to go back to check they hadn't missed something on the form).

### So which should you use for an empty field?

`readonly` if this is relaying information back to a user. They can still focus the field, hear the field label and that it is empty.

`disabled` if this control currently serves no purpose on the page (and is not likely to!) as it will be skipped entirely.

`disabled` should be used with caution due to the point I mentioned earlier that [some screen readers (VoiceOver) will skip `disabled` fields.](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/html/disabled_attribute).

Generally the rule is - does the user need to know that the field was left / is blank - use a `readonly`. Is this field not going to be used / not relevant while **inputting** information, use `disabled`.

**If in doubt use `readonly`, it will cause less harm than an erroneous `disabled` attribute.**

Comment: Thanks for the response @graham, I updated my question with a bit more context. I am familiar with `readonly` and `disabled` states. Since this is not simple page with standard process where you have a form in input mode and then at later stage you just get the preview of what you entered, it's a bit more harder to reason about. It probably comes down to whether this info is important to the user or not.
So for example, if this was some checkout process and in the final preview there were `empty` fields, I would definitely leave them as `readonly` so user can check what was left unfilled.

Comment: If they are actually `<input>` elements within the HTML then `readonly` is 100% the way to go, as I said the key behaviour is that `disabled` fields will not get read by some screen readers so your form above would essentially not exist if you used `disabled` on them. It is useful to know that the Metadata is not present I presume? lack of information is still information that is useful (if you know what I mean). Your alternative is to simply remove those fields for everybody if they are not needed. The main aim of accessibility is to provide as similar an experience as possible to everyone.

Comment: Yes, those fields are `<input>` elements, and metadata is not present for this specific person.

_The main aim of accessibility is to provide as similar an experience as possible to everyone_
With this in mind, I would say, it's better approach to remove those fields completely, as you suggested. Because if they are blank (in this specific use case), they don't provide any value, and sighted users would just skip them anyway. Will mark your answer as the correct one, as in general, it's the most accurate one, although it really depends on the context.